# Why is it so difficult to find the how to ask page?

Tags: discussion, help-center

I know there are already some questions about the general (lack of) findability of the how-to-ask page. This one is different however.

When I go to the help center, and just type "how to ask" in the searchbox there the how to ask page is only on the bottom of the page. Shouldn't it be one of the first results?

Comment: Yes. Finding this isn't easy, even for a veteran user. Even if you go the "Asking » View more" route, it's at the very bottom of a long list of links. Not hard to miss, especially if you aren't interested in going through a ton of material just to post a question on a Q&A site.

Comment: If you look it up to mention it in the comments: `[ask]` renders as "[ask]".

Comment: @Ivar, thanks thats brilliant. However it should still be higher up the search results

Comment: I always get to it through the help link at the bottom of every page.

Comment: [ask] it really works! [tour] so does `[tour]`

Comment: I think it's because the target audience of that page are new users asking their very first question on the site. It's a good reference to go back to once in a while, but the site probably expects users to familiarize themselves and get comfortable after their first few questions insofar that it's no longer essential reading for them. Of course, that's not to say there aren't people who ask large numbers of questions over many years with little to no sign of improvement...

Answer (score 3):

It's actually not that hard to find. It's up in your face every time you ask a question. Maybe people just don't read it.

IMO, the "How to Ask Questions" guide should be updated with the target audience in mind: **people stumbling on programming and StackOverflow for the first time, while frustrated by some bug.**

How can we encourage these people to read the question guide?

- Simplify the doc. Shorter sentences, smaller paragraphs, less text overall
- Make the value to question *askers* more clear
- Use concrete examples and easily understood analogies

Comment: I agree with your second bullet. The name might need to be changed from "How to Ask", which is too shallow imho. I expect anyone here to know that. The actual title of the page: ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) already sounds a lot better.

Comment: @JornVernee depends on the reader I think. Its very easy to follow that up with "... oh, so you think my question is shit?". "How do I ask a better question", perhaps. That does not instantly imply that yours is shit (even though it probably is) :)

Comment: *"less text overall"* It's already only about 1 screen page on a standard 1080p monitor. I'm not so sure if people who won't read that would read 2/3 of a page, and for those who do manage to read one page of guidelines you'd take away information.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Maybe the challenge is to make it feel less like a wall of text. Imho [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) does a really good job at this (also because it uses images with examples). Even though the amount of text is more or less the same, the tour is something you can scroll through to get a general idea of the information. The how-to-ask-page requires more effort (and patience) to get through.